# Does the Spring Security 6 automatically inject UserDetailsService while configuring under the hood?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Earlier, we had to override configure method from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}
```

But now in my case after I initialized an empty Spring Boot project with Spring Security I've noticed that it is enough to just only make a class which implements UserDetailsService and mark it as @Service and define PasswordEncoder bean to start default Spring Security login page and it will work fine. I don't even have any configuration files for Spring Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've noticed that it is enough to just only make a class which implements UserDetailsService and mark it as @Service and define PasswordEncoder bean to start default Spring Security login page and it will work fine.

That's a correct observation. Spring Security has moved to Component-based configuration since it's more flexible. In the absence of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, `configure()` methods are not useful anymore.

All you need is to register implementations of both `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder` as Beans in the Context. Either by defining methods annotated with `@Bean` or defining them as separate classes annotated using stereotype annotations (it's unlikely that you would use the latter option for `PasswordEncoder`, but it's doable).

When these Beans would be discovered at the application start-up, they would replace the default ones shipped by Spring Security. And AuthenticationProvider responsible for HTTP Basic authentication flow would use `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder` you've specified.